# Meaning of "ffprobe -v trace demo.mp4" output

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, ffprobe

The 'mdat box' of Mp4 file may at the last of file. I want to know the position of 'mdat' box using 'ffmpeg' or 'ffprobe'.

Mp4 consists of 'ftyp', 'moov' and 'mdat' BOX. each BOX consists of "BoxHeader" and "BoxData". "BoxHeader" consists of "BoxSize(4Byte)", "BoxType(4Byte)", "BoxLargesize(8Byte, only have when box size exceeding the range of 4Byte expression, then the value of BoxSize is 1)".

In program, you could first read 8 Byte and know the size of 'ftyp box', then seek the size and read 8 Byte to know if the next box is 'moov box'. If not 'moov', it shoud be 'mdat box', then seek cross 'mdat box' to find 'mdat box'...

But I want to use 'ffprobe' to find the position of 'moov'. I use 'ffprobe -v trace demo.mp4', and output is like below

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc8fd000e00] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 probed with size=2048 and score=100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc8fd000e00] type:'ftyp' parent:'root' sz: 28 8 41044500
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc8fd000e00] ISO: File Type Major Brand: mp42
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc8fd000e00] type:'moov' parent:'root' sz: 17943 36 41044500
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7fc8fd000e00] type:'mvhd' parent:'moov' sz: 108 8 17935
```

I want to know the meaning of `type:'ftyp' parent:'root' sz: 28 8 41044500`:
`type:'ftyp' parent:'root'`is easy to know, `sz: 28 8 41044500` is really make me confused, I guess `28` is size of ftyp box,but the meaning of  `8 41044500` is what?

Could you explain the meaning of `sz: 28 8 41044500`, and where could find the doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

```
type:'mvhd' parent:'moov' sz: 108 8 17935
```

type and parent represent the type of the current and parent box respectively.

There are three values for `sz` (size).

The first value, `108` represents the total size of the current box, including the header.

The second value, `8`, represents the starting offset of the box data relative to the start of the box header. This is needed because box size can be 8 bytes and box type can have a UUID, in which case, may be up to 20 bytes long. This offset will be non-zero even if the box has no data e.g. `free`.

The third value, `17935`, is the data size of the parent box.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, Thanks. I also want to know where else could I find the meaning of the number? from ffmpeg doc? or ffmpeg Mailing Lists?

Comment: To solve a bug that ijkplayer can't play mp4 which `moov` is after `mdat` in the android asset dir, I found the ffprobe output info is in ffmpeg 'libavformat/mov.c' mov_read_default function, like `av_log(c->fc, AV_LOG_WARNING, "type:'%s' parent:'%s' sz: %"PRId64" %"PRId64" %"PRId64"\n",
               av_fourcc2str(a.type), av_fourcc2str(atom.type), a.size, total_size, atom.size);`. code is the best document and code is the badest document.